# What is nlp in spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

Usually we start from:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_encore_web_sm') # or medium, or large
```

or

```
nlp = English()
```

then:

```
doc = nlp('my text')
```

Then we can do a lot of fun with that even not knowing the nature of the first line.

But what exactly is 'nlp'? What is going on under the hood? Is "nlp" a pretrained model, as understood in machine learning, and therefore some big file located somewhere on the disc?

I met an explanation, that 'nlp' is an 'object, containing process pipeline', but that only explains a little.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question about non-working code, and should probably be on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Some research in the Spacy docs or forums would also probably directly answer your question; in particular, I think you're asking about the [`Doc`](https://spacy.io/api/doc) object.

Comment: @kwinkunks I am asking about a step preceding the Doc intantiating, not a Doc object.

Comment: SO has a lot of useful info not only about "not working code". E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 2):

You can always check the type of any python objects:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_encore_web_sm') # or medium, or large
print(type(nlp))
print(dir(nlp))  # view a list of attributes
```

You will get something like this (depending on the passed arguments)

```
<class 'spacy.lang.en.English'>
```

You are right it is something like 'pretrained' model as it contains vocabulary, binary weights, etc.

Please check the official documentation:

https://spacy.io/api/language

Answer (score 0):

You could infer what `nlp()` is by exploring it. For example:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

text = "Elon Musk 889-888-8888 elonpie@tessa.net Jeff Bezos (345)123-1234 bezzi@zonbi.com Reshma Saujani example.email@email.com 888-888-8888 Barkevious Mingo"

text = nlp(text)

print(text)
```

Will print the exact same text. On the other hand if you do:

```
for word in text.ents:
    print(word.text,word.label_)
```

you will get the entities of the string:

```
Elon Musk PERSON
889-888 CARDINAL
Jeff Bezos PERSON
345)123 CARDINAL
Reshma Saujani PERSON
```

It is indeed large pre-trained model for the English language and has many functions (parser, lemmatizer, tagger) as the one demonstrated above. Hope this helps a bit to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

`nlp` is a spaCy pipeline. You can see the details on it here: https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm

Pipelines contain multiple components, in this case:

- **tok2vec**: Token-to-Vector model for tokenizing and vectorizing text
- **tagger**: Part-of-speech (POS) tagger
- **parser**: Dependency parser
- **attribute_ruler**: Attribute mapping based on rules
- **lemmatizer**: Lemmatization (base forms of words)
- **ner**: Named entity recognition

Hope this helps. There's more details in the documentation on Pipelines here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

spaCy is a popular library in the NLP (Natural Language Processing) field and is designed for production use. When you use the function spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') or initialize an English() object, you're creating an NLP processing pipeline.

1.nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm'):

This loads a pre-trained model named en_core_web_sm, which is one of
spaCy's small English models. This model comes with several capabilities
out-of-the-box, such as tokenization, part-of-speech tagging, named entity
recognition, and dependency parsing.

2.nlp = English():

This creates a blank English processing pipeline. It will not contain the
capabilities of en_core_web_sm because it's not loading any pre-trained
models. It will primarily tokenize your text, but without the additional
annotations like part-of-speech tags or named entities.

3.Pipeline:

When you call doc = nlp('my text'), the text is processed by the nlp
pipeline. Depending on the model or how you've set it up, it will tokenize
the text, tag parts of speech, parse dependencies, recognize named
entities, and potentially more.